# Excel: stop cells formatting being applied to adjacent cell?

Tags: excel, vsto, vba

I noticed that if I format (font, color, etc.) a certain number of cells in a row or in a column, as soon as I type text in adjacent cells in the same row or column formatting is automatically applied to the added cell. How can this automatic behavior be stopped? I'm formatting cells programmatically and style/color if often defined conditionally, it is not simply to please the eye or to make data more readable and excel's automatic formatting is setting formatting/color without knowledge of the underlying logic. Formatting is not being set via formulas but via C# code.

Comment: "...formatting cells programmatically and style/color if often defined conditionally..."  Are you using VBA, or C#? What's the code you're using? Are you in a table, or is it plain data?

Comment: I'm using C#. It's plain data which I'm formatting to speed up data reading/interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled by a setting of the Excel Application Object:

```
YourExcelObjectReference.Application.ExtendList = False
```

Comment: I confirm that the "issue" which was not a real issue but a feature :) was due to Excel's "extend data range formats and formulas". Your line of code works fine although it disables the option in Excel. This option should be something defined at the workbook level not at the application/client level.

Comment: Perhaps, but there are many settings like this one, which a (VBA) developer must turn off and back on again (or at least back in the previous state).